# Why update operation on one collection blocks read from another?

Tags: mongodb

I have an issue with my mongoDB, I am running one mongo instance on the server. I have several collections in the db - the problem I'm running into is that when I run a long update operation (150k records) in **myRecords** collection, any read query in **myDetails** will be blocked until that long update operation is complete.

This doesn't make much sense to me, I can see how reading from the same collection might be blocked during the update, but why would another be affected? Am I missing something?

More details:

-running nodejs and performing operations with javascript

-db version v3.0.11

-mmapv1

Comment: What mongodb version? What storage engine?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev added extra details.

Comment: According to documentation, mmapv1 since version 3 should be able to do collection-level locking. So your situation shouldn't happen. I have no idea what's going on there.